# Compare the time stamp of Suse linux

Tags: linux, timestamp, stat

I am try to compare the two time file based on their modify/lastchange time stamp & then copy the file to some folder  code below

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /sapmnt/audit/
echo $PWD
t1= stat -c %z audit.log20151019115132
cd /var/log/audit/
echo $PWD
t2= stat -c %z audit.log.3
echo $t1
echo $t2
if [ $t2 -nt $t1 ];
then
echo "PASS"
else
   echo "Fail"
fi
```

output:

```
/sapmnt/audit
2015-10-19 11:51:32.189657200 +0000
/var/log/audit
2015-10-20 17:25:01.000000000 +0000


PASS
```

The problem is that it always output Pass either if  i exchange the condition to the `[ $t1 -nt $t2 ]`.

Answer (score 1):

`-nt` and `-ot` work directly on files, not on values.

```
#!/bin/sh

t1='/sapmnt/audit//audit.log20151019115132'
t2='/var/log/audit/audit.log.3'
echo $t1
echo $t2
if [ $t2 -nt $t1 ];
then
echo "PASS"
else
   echo "Fail"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

according to `man test`

> FILE1 -nt FILE2
>
> FILE1 is newer (modification date) than FILE2

`-nt` operator will compare file, not timestamp.